# Wie sagt man “according to our policy”?

Tags: word-usage, english-to-german, phrase, expression

Google Translate hat mir *Politik* für *policy* empfohlen. Ich bin mir aber nicht sicher, dass ich dieses Wort im Sinne von „according to our company’s policy“ nutzen kann.

Kann man sagen:

> Laut unserer Politik

Oder:

> *"Laut unserer [Firmen]Regeln

Gibt es einen feststehenden Ausdruck für *according to our policy* im Deutschen?

Comment: Einige Hinweise: 1. *sich sicher sein* ist reflexiv (Dativ), also muss es *ich bin **mir** sicher* heißen; 2. *Sinn* ist maskulin; und im feststehenden Ausdruck *im Sinne von* hat sich das Dativ-*e* erhalten (aber man kann es auch weglassen); 3. *fixed expression* = *feststehender Ausdruck*. ^^

Comment: @Jan danke schön :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ich würde das Wort *Richtlinien* verwenden. Wird gerne mit der Präposition *gemäß* (+ Dativ) verwendet. Also zum Beispiel:

> Gemäß unseren Richtlinien

Comment: Vielen Dank! Ich habe diese Phrase vielmal gesehen, aber hab mich daran nicht erinnern. Deutsch ist erstaunlich! :)

Answer (score 1):

Vielleicht auch

> dem Leitbild unseres Unternehmens entsprechend, bzw.
>
> nach / gemäß unserem Leitbild

oder

> die Leitlinien unserer Unternehmenspolitik geben vor ..., bzw.
>
> ... ist / sind mit den Leitlinien unseres Unternehmens (nicht) vereinbar

oder

> es gehört zu unserer Unternehmensphilosophie, dass ... / zu ....

In etwas stärker umgangssprachlich geprägter Ausdrucksweise kann man
in den zusammengesetzten Substantiven 'Unternehmens-' durch 'Firmen-' ersetzen.